# Which one better technique of html in php code?

Tags: php, html

Which one better technique for code from below "technique 1" and "technique 2"

"technique 1"

```
<?php
  for($i=0; $i<=10; $i++)
  {
     echo '<div>Row data '.$i.'</div>';
  }
?>
```

"technique 2"

```
<?php
  for($i=0; $i<=10; $i++)
  {
     ?> <div>Row data <?php echo $i; ?> </div> <?php
  }
?>
```

Comment: Both are "bad" practices... think about the "separation of concerns"

Comment: I prefer technique 2

Comment: Technique 2, makes it easier to manage larger chunks of code.

Comment: this question is opinion based. going to flag off toipic

Comment: Can you define "better" please?

Comment: thank's all of you. "B001" can you talk to me why "think about the separation of concerns".

Comment: Thank you for your opinion... I am not gonna tell the whole principle which 
 belongs to making a proper research @NappingRabbit

Comment: No dear "B001". Just i need of knowledge like technique 2 is better for it but any special difference in this technique on development side

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I recommend to use one of PHP template engines like Twig, Blade etc.
Second, if you wish to avoid T.E. and use one of build-in ways in PHP I would recommend [Alternative syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php):

```
<?php for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++): ?>
    <div>Row data <?= $i; ?> </div>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

Comment: what is `T.E.` ?

Comment: @NappingRabbit abbreviation for template engine

Comment: thank you, I should have inferred that from the context

Answer (score 0):

I suppose both of those are similar.  I think the first looks neater, some prefer the second.

I prefer to build a string of `html` and then spit it out, likely a throwback to when performance was a problem and concatenation was faster than display, so `concatenate` and then `echo once`.  I am pretty sure it is just opinion and choice now.  (I use tabs too, and open brackets on the same line, unless the IDE moves it for me...  more choice and opinion)
Here is an example of a way:

somewhere is a class:

```
    function showAThing(){
      $thing = new MakeAThing();
      echo($thing->htmlOut);
    }
```

in the MakeAThing Class:

```
  var $htmlOut;

  function __construct(){
      for($i=0; $i<=10; $i++){
         $this->htmlOut .= '<div>Row data '.$i.'</div>';
      }
  }
```

of course this is a contrived example.  You can `abstract` it further if you like too but it just gets annoying after a bit.

[here is a link](http://thisinterestsme.com/mixing-php-html/) to a guy with an opinion.  I dont agree with it totally, but whatever.